# LAST COLUMN VALUE IN GOOGLE SHEETS

Tags: google-sheets-formula

first time on here.

I need to create a formula that will always return the last payment date each of my clients has made (lowest row).
I tried using Index and vlookup but wasn't able to figure it out.
It's important for me to keep the table tidy and not fill it with zeroes for the count functions to work.

Example here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1APpxJ3xoTjV1VrXKnaUyFoy5HpuqLo0U4UqfXdQLZRE/edit?usp=sharing

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sprw.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in B31

```
=arrayformula(query(sort({row($A3:$A31),{$A3:$A30;0},{B3:B30;""}},1,0),"select Col2 where Col3 is not null limit 1"))
```

then drag to right

Comment: That worked!
But for some weird reason after dragging to the the formula in Col H hops down one cell.
Can be solved by adding a date in the last cell in Col A.

Comment: yes, that's weird, you can prevent that by filling in a date after the last one, or in A30 as you did. curiously, this happens for the last row! I think this is due to the reverse sorting process.

Comment: I found a solution to prevent this behavior by adding a dummy row, see my updated answer